# What is the difference between NFTables and BPFilter?

Tags: iptables, openwrt, nftables

I trying to secure my home network with OpenWRT routers. In this context I started to customize my iptables rules to my needs and found some iptables concepts hard to understand.

I've discovered that **nftables** is the NEXT big change in firewall software for Linux based systems (as of ~3.18), replacing iptables which is hard to use or inefficient. More recently, I've learnt **bpfilter** is being merged into Linux 4.18 and it is a "Better Firewall / Packet Filtering" also meant to replace **iptables**.

Now, I'm quite confused: could you give me a one sentence description of each technology, *nftables/netfilter vs bpfilter*? Are they both trying to solve the same problem / do they overlap? Is there any relationship between the two? I am looking for a short description of each to understand when to use one or the other.

Comment: [Is there any tooling for bpfilter allowing to configure a firewall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357292/is-there-any-tooling-for-bpfilter-allowing-to-configure-a-firewall/54363894#54363894) . Well the main difference as of today (or a few months ago), is it's really hard to try and use bpfilter, and for now it would just translate iptables features rather than being a full-fledged tool. So the question becomes for now: "What is the difference between nftables and iptables?".